# IntByReference returns 0 instead of the actual value

Tags: java, eclipse, native, jna

I have the following C code which I am calling from JNA. When I call it I am getting 0 as the return value while I'm getting the real value when I test it in C.

```
RFIDLIB_API uint32_t get(
ipj_key key                         /*[i]*/,
uint32_t bank_index             /*[in]*/,
uint32_t value_index                        /*[out]*/,
uint32_t *value /*[out]*/)
{
return ipj_get(&iri_device,key,bank_index,value_index,value);

}
```

Below is how I have defined this in my JNA library.

```
public int get(ipj_key key, int bank_index, int value_index, IntByReference value);
```

Below is the ip_key structure

```
public class ipj_key extends Structure {

public int ipj_key;

@Override
protected List getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("ipj_key");
}

}
```

And below is how I am calling it in my main method.

```
public rfidlib rlib;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainScannerTest mainClass = new MainScannerTest();
    mainClass.rlib = (rfidlib) Native.loadLibrary("rfidlib", rfidlib.class);

    ipj_key key = new ipj_key();
    key.ipj_key = 0xD;
    IntByReference value = new IntByReference();

    mainClass.rlib.get(key, 0, 0, value);
    System.out.println("Antenna power is : "+ value.getValue());

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I getting 0 as the return value? Please advice.

Comment: Your `value_index` is also marked as `[out]` but you're passing a value, not a reference.

Comment: If you're worried that the native code is not changing the value, initialize the `IntByReference` to a different value.

Answer (score 0):

My C lib has a `int*` as an `OUT` parameter. I was also trying to use it with an `IntByReference`, without any success.

EDIT 2017-03-16: indeed it worked with IntByReference. There might me something wrong in your C code.

An alternative would be using a `Pointer` instead of `IntByreference`
(I made it work with IntByRef and also with Pointer in my case (64bit Win7, JNA 4.3.0 and Java 64 bits jdk 1.8.0_71))

With your code snippet, this would look like the following.

First change your JNA dll interface defintion (use Pointer instead of IntByReference):

```
public int get(ipj_key key, int bank_index, int value_index, /*change is here*/ Pointer value);
```

Then change of course the variable before call:

```
Pointer value = new Memory(Integer.size); // Here we assume that your java platform is 32 bits (Integer.size=32)
//this should match your uint32_t. No idea if there are consequences when mixing 32/64 bits java/OS/dll ...
```

Then, you can do the following:

```
System.out.println("Antenna power is : "+ value.getInt(0));
// The offset is set to 0, since there is no reason to read the int from another offset value.
```